# Between real analysis and mathematical logic

Tags: real-analysis, lo.logic

This question lies in the intersection of real analysis and logic, so I try to keep things rather basic.

First of all, logicians care about the following kind of formula:

Let $\varphi(n, x)$ be a formula with parameters $n$ (over the natural numbers) and $x$ (over the real numbers) such that $(\forall n\in \mathbb{N})(\exists \text{ at most one } x\in [0,1])\varphi(n, x)$.

This kind of formula has a nice connection to real analysis via the following function:

$$ f(x):=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2^n} & \text{in case $n$ is the least number such that $\varphi(n, x)$}\\
0 & \text{in case $\neg\varphi(m, x)$ for all natural numbers $m$}  
\end{cases}
 $$

The function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ has bounded variation (in the sense of Jordan).  Hence, theorems of real analysis (like the Jordan decomposition theorem) establish properties of the aforementioned formulas $\varphi$.

Secondly, my question is whether the above extends to two or more dimensions.

Now let $\psi(n, x, y)$ be a formula with parameters $n$ (over the natural numbers) and $x, y$ (over the real numbers) such that $(\forall n\in \mathbb{N})(\exists \text{ at most one } x\in [0,1])(\forall y\in [0,1])\psi(n, x, y)$.

Now consider the following 'two-dimensional' version of $f$ above:
$$ g(x, y):=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2^n} & \text{in case $n$ is the least number such that $\psi(n, x, y)$}\\
0 & \text{in case $\neg\psi(m, x, y)$ for all natural numbers $m$}  
\end{cases}
 $$

Does $g$ belong to a (nice/known) function class from analysis? If not, is there a modification of $g$ that does?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is the formula $n<2\land n=0\to(x\in\mathbb{Q}\leftrightarrow y\in\mathbb{Q})\land n=1\to(x\in\mathbb{Q}\leftrightarrow y\notin\mathbb{Q})$. Then we have that $g(x,y)=1$ whenever $\lvert\mathbb{Q}\cap\{x,y\}\rvert\neq1$ and $g(x,y)=0.5$ otherwise. This seems like a fairly wild function analytically speaking, though my last proper analysis class was a while ago...